# How do I manage common data when creating microservices

Tags: microservices

Im refactoring a monolith to microservies. I am not clear on data responsibility and access with microservices. From what I read we should take vertical slices.
So each service should be responsible for its own UI/WebAPI/DB, with distinct responsibility.
For example if I had a monolith shopping cart app, I could break it into the following services:

- CustomerAccount
- ProductSearch
- ProductMaintenance
- ShoppingCart
- Ordering

What do I do with shared data, how do I determine what part of the system is responsible for it?

e.g. In my shopping cart example...

- The CustomerAccount, ShoppingCart and Ordering need to know about the Customer data.
- The ProductSearch, ProductMaintenance, ShoppingCart and Ordering need to know about Product Data data.
- The Ordering will update the number of products available, but so should the productMaintenance.

So should the services send messages back and forth to get data from one another, 
or should there be a master service, which handles the communication/workflow between services
or should they read/write from a common database
or something else?

Comment: Monolith applications arent that bad if you design them well. Clearly you have no experience in designing microservice-based applications, are you sure this is a good idea, or it's just a requirement you got from your employer? Is your scale large enough? I'm just curious what were the reasons to go after microservices. Each service should be independent from each other, meaning different database, different servers, are you up to that? There's no room for "a common database". If there's any common part, of services has to be deployed in a specific order those are not m-services per se anymore

Comment: No I havent used microservices before. My monolith isnt actually a shopping cart, but I gave that example as it would be easier for people to understand. Our system is large, complex and hard to maintain in its current state. But the issue about sharing/communicating data applies to both.

Comment: I am not convinced you are looking at this from the right angle. Definitely improve your system, the fact that it's a monolith is neither here nor there. Do not touch micro-services unless you know very well what you are doing, otherwise you will replace a big mess which works with a bigger mess which doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

*This seem little late to answer but it may be good for future use.*

Microservice calling another Microservice is totally fine, what you should be aware of is in case the communication between Microservices becomes to chatty  than you should look at a different solution(maybe duplication of data across services, or have it with in same service).

In your case I would build a separate services for each entity that you call for common and reevaluate the situation afterwards.

Hope this helps

Best regrads
Burim